# IE flexbox centered layout ignore height

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I have a layout made with flexbox. In Safari/Chrome/Firefox/Opera it works fine, the only problem is Internet Explorer (version <= 11).

The layout I want to have is the following:

```
*-----------------*
| HEADER          |
*-----------------*
|                 |
|  *-----------*  |
|  |           |  |
|  |           |  |
|  *-----------*  |
|                 |
*-----------------*
```

The content is always centerd both vertically and horizontally. That's how I achieve this:

```
  .app {
      background-color: $white;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100vh;

      &__header {
          flex: 0 1 auto;
          height: 50px;
      }

      &__content {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;

          flex: 1 1 auto;                     /*  changed flex-shrink to 1  */
          display: flex;
          align-items: flex-start;            /*  IE fix  */
          overflow-y: auto;
          padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
      }
  }
```

The problem is that when the height of the content is greater than the height of the window IE reduces the height of the header (that should be fixed) and doesn't leave any padding:

[image]

while every other browser leave the padding as specified in the &__content CSS rule:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you want Flexbox to work in IE10, you need to add -ms--prefix.
Flexbox doesn't work in IE9 and below, as stated here: https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20flex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `header` has its `flex-shrink` set to `1`, which allows it to shrink.

Change it to `flex: 0 0 auto` and it will work in IE as well.

*Note, using `flex-basis` for height is the preferred way for flex column items, `flex: 0 0 50px`*

---

Updated based on a comment

If the case of content that will exceed its parent's height (`app__content`), and parent use `align-items: center;`, the content will [overflow at both top and bottom](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-align-items-center), and it does by design.

To fix such issue, remove `align-items: center` and use `margin: auto 0` on the content.

Comment: The header now doesn't shrink, thanks! But the height problem remains, I can't see the beginning of the page because it overflows from the top...

Comment: @ste After a second look at your posted code, I deleted my update. To be able to tell why it overflow at the top, I need to see a code sample reproducing just that. Also, that issue is not mentioned in the question, and if it is not a quick fix, you should accept the answer that solved this question, and then post a new for the other issue.

Comment: @ste Added an adjusted update back, as a general explanation.

Comment: Actually you provided me the right answer: I set flex-shrink to 1 also in the content, changed that to 0 and now it works :)